# Windows 8, many setup files don't start, unless I run them as administrator

Tags: windows-8

I recently installed Windows 8 on my computer. I have just one user, connected to a Microsoft account.

My problem is that many setup files (Chrome, Flash, Dropbox, just to mention a few), if launched with a double click, just don't start. If I right-click and choose run as administrator they run fine. Is this normal on Win 8, or there's a problem with my configuration?

**EDIT**

I temporarily solved the problem by creating a new local account, but after some days the problem started again.

Installers that have problem include:

- The nVidia graphics driver installer
- Chrome setup
- Dropbox setup (I solved this by modifying the temp directory permissions allow read/write access to Users)
- Steam install (MSI installer) gives error 1723 "A DLL required [...] could not be run"
- Google Play music manager (if I run it as admin, the prorgam is installed but with graphical problems)

Comment: Have you upgraded to Windows 8, or did you do a clean install?

Comment: Clean, and also reinstalled again for another problem. I've sorted out the problem, which regards the permissions of the Temp folder. I'm still not sure on how they got changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your UAC settings. Sounds like you've got it set to `Always Deny` or disabled entirely so that you're not being prompted to approve elevated access.

Alternatively it may be a permissions issue. Make sure that `AppData\Local\Temp` is set to allow Administrators full access, Users read-only access and YOURUSERNAME full access.

Comment: UAC settings are as default and they are ok, and I receive prompts. For example, the nVidia driver setup prompted for elevated access, but then the setup program terminates. I managed to start the setup by running the file from an administrator command prompt

Comment: What happens if you run the setup in Windows 7 compatibility mode?

Comment: I just modified the permissions on `AppData\Local\Temp` to allow complete access to `Everyone` and now the installers run fine. Have the default permissions on the temp folder changed since Windows 7? Do you think this would be harmful for my PC?

Comment: You'd expect it to allow Administrators full access, Users read-only access and YOURUSERNAME full access. Anything other than that would be an issue.

Comment: @Pincopallino - No...They have not changed the fact you had to change them indicates a serious problem with your installation.

Comment: @PhonicUK I set the permission as you told me and it works good. In the security tab I had only Administrators and Everyone. I added manually my user and the Users group.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect that. Although there is the issue of how they got changed from that in the first place, but at least you're okay now.

Comment: @Ramhound, this is a fresh isntallation of Windows 8

Comment: @PhonicUK I'm not sure how they got changed. I guess the only possibility is a setup file. Maybe Norton Internet Security?

Comment: I won't award this answer with the bounty because I actually solved the problem myself. The answer might still be useful for other people.

Comment: The bounty will be automatically awarded to the highest ranked answer after a while, so it's kind of moot in either case.